# PrimeFaces and PrimeFaces-mobile compatibility

Tags: jsf, primefaces, primefaces-mobile

I have an old project using PrimeFaces-mobile and PrimeFaces and I’m trying to update it to the latest versions however I’m having some compatibility issues.

What is the newest  PrimeFaces version compatible with PrimeFaces-mobile, version 1.0 snapshot? I tried 3.5, 4.0, 5.0 and 5.2 but only 3.5 seems to work. With any other version, I get an empty page because jQuery adds `display: none` to my page.

Thx

Comment: I had PrimeFaces Mobile 1.0 snapshot running with 4.1 snapshot. think with the release of version 5.0 mobile was merged into core project. You can still find the "old" 4.1 snapshot here: https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots/org/primefaces/primefaces/4.1-SNAPSHOT/

Comment: Thx! After I removed the primefaces-mobile reference from my pom, primefaces 5.2 worked. Not sure, but I think my problem was due to the incompatibility between the new jquery versions and jquery-mobile.